# nginx, rewrite url is not working

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

my rewrite URL is not working, here is part of nginx config with rewrite. Thanks for any advice.

```
 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @mylocation;
}

location @mylocation {
        rewrite ^index.php?p=/profile(.*)$ /profile/ redirect;
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by «not working»? BTW, first `rewrite` is wrong. You cannot match query parameters in rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests never reach `@mylocation`, as I assume index.php exists ...

Try something like this

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
 }
 location /index.php {
    if ($args ~* "^p=/profile.*") {
            rewrite ^ /profile/? redirect;
    }
 }
```